# generators of the intersection and addition of two ideals genrated by positive integers m,n in athe ring of integers

Tags: ring-theory

let $\mathbb Z$ be the ring of integers. $A=\langle m \rangle$ and $B=\langle n \rangle$. then $A+B=\langle d \rangle$ and $A \cap B = \langle l \rangle$. where $d = \gcd(m,n)$ and $l=\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.
if some one can prove it please give me some hint.

Comment: Can you show inclusion in one of the directions in either of the two cases?

Comment: ican't understand what you are saying?

Comment: You have some sets you want to show are equal. To do this, you need to show that each is contained in the other. Can you show any of these inclusions?

Comment: i got both inclusion in A$\cap$B.

Comment: So you don't actually need help with that one?

Comment: yes. but help me in A+B

Comment: Hint: Use Bezout's identity.

Comment: what is Bezout's identity?

Comment: I need to go now. Google will tell you about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x\in A$ means $x$ is a multiple of $m$, and $x\in B$ means $x$ is a multiple of $n$, so $x\in A\cap B$ means $x$ is a common multiple of $m$ and $n$.